# Wait for either condition A or condition B in a std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stl

I have what seems a fairly simple need, but I'm new to using std::thread and am not sure I understand it right.

My thread's job is to run a loop: wait until an object needs processing, then process it, then wait, ...

I was about to implement this using a `condition_variable` before I realised that while the thread is sat idly waiting for a new object, it won't notice a `stopThread` flag has been set.

I effectively want a way to do `wait_for_either(new_data,exit_thread)` but am unsure how to elegantly implement this. Older code of similar queue function uses Windows API `WaitForMultipleObjects` but I want to use this as an opportunity to learn the C++11 way.

Answer (score 4):

When you wait for data to process, you are actually waiting for the condition variable to be signalled. So just signal the condition variable when you want to exit the thread, just as if the `stopThread` flag were a special data to be processed.

The code might look like:

```
void thread_func()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    for (;;)
    {
        cond.wait(lock, [] () { return stopThread || !dataContainer.empty(); });
        if (stopThread)
            return; //exit thread
        //process data from dataContainer
    }
}
```

To insert data:

```
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    dataContainer.push_back(new_data);
    cond.notify_all();
}
```

And then, when you want to stop the thread:

```
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    stopThread = true;
    cond.notify_all();
}
thread.join(); //not necessary but probably a good idea
```

Comment: I think you meant to use `wait` and not `wait_for`.  `wait_for` needs a duration specified.

Comment: This would be using `condition_var_any`, right? I assume that the condition function is simply called periodically - does this function need to be thread safe or is that guaranteed?

Comment: @Mr.Boy. `std::condition_variable` or `std::condition_variable_any`, it does not matter. The condition function will be called whenever other thread calls `notify_one()` or `notify_all()`, and it will be called with the associated lock locked, so you can access shared data from there.

Comment: To the OP and anyone else messing with condition variables: Please read up on how the lambda part of the `.wait` call works.  It can and will be evaluated spuriously (with the lock held).  (This answer uses it correctly, at least as far as I can tell, right now)

Comment: @rodrigo might you flesh out slightly your answer? I'm unsure how to control modifying `stopThread` in a thread-safe manner... won't your `wait` call stall the associated mutex?

Comment: @Mr.Boy: To modify `stopThread` safely, do it with the lock held. I have added the lock calls in my answer. As you can see, every read or write of `stopThread` is done with the lock held, so the code is safe.

Comment: @rodrigo thanks for the edit. I still have lock confusion though. Isn't the lock in `thread_func()` going to mean other attempts to lock the same mutex will block indefinitely?

Comment: @Mr.Boy: No, that's the beauty of condition variables. The `wait()` call first **releases the mutex**, then waits for the notification. When the notification eventually arrives, the mutex is re-locked and the condition checked. If the condition returns false, the lock is released again and it goes to wait again. If the condition returns true, `wait()` returns with the mutex locked. And all this race-free!

Comment: Ah, that's the missing piece. Thankyou very much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a robust data consuming loop with abort options:

```
while(true) {
  decltype(dataContainer) data;
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    cond.wait(lock, [] () { return stopThread || !dataContainer.empty(); });
    if (stopThread)
      return; //exit thread
    data = std::move(dataContainer);
  }
  for (auto&& d:data) {
    if (stopThread) return; // abort
    //process data from d
  }
}
```

`stopThread` should be `atomic` or access in the `for(:)` loop at the bottom needs be guarded with a `mutex`.

The access to `stopThread` in the `for(:)` loop is optional; without it, it won't abort until it finishes working on the bundle of work it picked up.

`dataContainer` is a bundle of work to do in the form of a `std::vector` or somesuch.  The thread wakes up, grabs all the work to-do, then works on it.

You could also pop one task from `dataContainer` instead of taking them all.  The resulting code is a touch simpler.

To queue data into `dataContainer`, you have to lock the `mutex`, put the data in, then notify:

```
{
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
  dataContainer.push_back(new_data);
}
cond.notify_one();
```

to shut down:

```
{
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
  stopThread = true;
}
cond.notify_all();
```

Note that even if `stopThread` is atomic, you need to acquire the mutex.  There is otherwise a race condition.

Comment: I like how you pull the data out and then release the lock, so more entries can be queued while processing the current one. Can I manually release the lock after pulling the data out to get the same effect?

Comment: @Mr.Boy Sure, that could work.  Be careful when messing around with lock status explicitly; scoped locks are far easier to reason about.

Answer (score 0):

Semi - pseudo code.

```
std::atomic_bool programRunning;
std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex mtx;

std::thread loopThread([&]{
   while(programRunning.load()){
       std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        if (newDataAvailable){
            //process new data
        } else{
            cv.wait(lock,[&]{ return dataAvailable || !progamRunning.load(); });
        }
   }

});

{
   std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
   queueMoreData();
   cv.notify_one();
}

//on exit:
programRunning.store(false);
cv.notify_one();
```

Comment: I get you're using lambdas but what is the `[&] {...}` syntax?

Comment: catch everything by reference, no arguments

Comment: I'd do a forever-loop, wait, and break myself.  Also, you should make your `newDataAvailable` have the same name.  ;)  Next, you probably don't want to hold the mutex for the entire period you are processing the data; that makes people queing up new data have to wait for the old data to be processed.

Comment: @Yakk I was thinking that too. Also if I use a regular bool and a lock to control access to `programRunning` this implies my mutex will get 'stalled' - I can't add new data as the thread always has it locked while it waits for data. Using two mutexes seems a bit OTT.